Tutorial of lattice estimator to compute a specific function with BGV

I recently try to go into lattice estimator https://github.com/malb/lattice-estimator

I did find the document of it, but unfortunately, can not follow.

May I ask how to run the lattice estimator to get the parameters of BGV computation, for specific functions like inner product with fix security parameters (e.g., 128 bits) both with and without bootstrapping?

Would appreciate for any resource for this.
Thanks a lot
